# dumping mongodb database to sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I have dumped a mongodb database(stand alone server) to a sharded database by using mongodump binary.
somehow in the new sharded database the count of items in one of the collections has increased by 2Mil.
any one knows the reason for that?